# Should [beer] be moved to [alcoholic-beverages]?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

Today, I was surprised that Worldbuilding Stack Exchange has a tag called [beer], yet there were no tags called [wine], [alcohol], or [alcoholic-beverages].

In addition, there were many questions about [wine](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=wine) or other [alcoholic beverages](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=alcohol), yet they did not have a specific tag. I think that it is unnecessary to have a tag on beer rather than just a general tag about alcohol. After all, [fantasy] was moved to [magic].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An "alcohol" tag would probably be much better, and make keeping "beer" confusing.

"alcoholic-beverages" would also work.

Answer (score 4):

I went into this expecting to defend the 'beer' tag and suggesting we also open an 'alcohol' tag.

Then I searched for the 'beer' tag, and saw **there were only 2 questions that use it**, the newest of which was over 2 years old.  With that said, comparing "beer" and "wine" as search terms yielded very similar results (410 and 380, respectively).

I'm indifferent on opening up an Alcohol tag, but I'm fully onboard with burninating any tag that has fewer than 10 uses and that has not been used in the past 2 years.

Answer (score 2):

Concur with Mary. Having tags that are little used is indicative that querents, especially new ones, are unaware of the variety of tags we've got (honestly, I didn't even know we have a "beer" tag). Eliminating tags doesn't help much; good management of tags will improve the functionality of this forum. I'd be in favour of creating an "alcoholic beverages" tag; I'd also be in favour of creating a "wine" tag. I'd rather not eliminate the "beer" tag.